# Setting parent-children relationships in constructor without leaking "this" variable

Tags: java, constructor, thread-safety

I am writing some physics code that organizes objects into a hierarchical relationship, with each object of class Body having one parent (a subclass handles the root conditions) and zero to many children.  However, in order to instantiate a new Body, I must add it to its parent, and thus the constructor leaks "this" to the addChild method of its parent.

Currently the addChild method of Body is private; the only way to access it outside of Body's constructor is via Body.setParent.  However, I am concerned that there may be edge cases in which this still may expose a non-fully instantiated object.  The code below is simplified to only the relevant elements:

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Body {
    private Body parent;
    private Set<Body> children;

    public Body(Body parent) {
        // instantiates everything else first
        this.children = new TreeSet<Body>;
        this.parent = parent;

        parent.addChild(this);
    }

    public void setParent(Body parent) {
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.addChild(this);
    }

    private void addChild(Body child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    private void removeChild(Body child) {
        children.remove(child);
    }
}
```

As expected, this code is "Leaking this in constructor," but there does not appear to be any way to set up the tree structure otherwise.  Is there another design pattern which could be used to avoid the potential of Body being visible before its constructor finishes running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to keep the constructor simple.  In your case it is complicated by interacting with another object.  One reason is error handling which can be difficult in constructors.

Instead of using a constructor with a parameter, remove the parameter and call it like this.

```
var newBody = new Body();
newBody.setParent(parent);
```

The constructor would look like this.

```
public Body() {
    this.children = new TreeSet<Body>;
}
```

And change the setParent method to check for no current parent.

```
public synchronized void setParent(Body newParent) {
    if (parent != null)
        parent.removeChild(this);
    parent = newParent;
    if (newParent != null)
        newParent.addChild(this);
}
```

Notice that I also changed the name of the setParent parameter to not collide with the class variable.  Hard to find errors occur when you forget to use "this" in order to distinguish which "parent" you are referring to.

The constructor code I removed was really just a duplication of the setParent method anyway.

I added synchronized to the method so that you are assured that multiple calls to this method are done synchronously, otherwise the hierarchy could get damaged.

Of course, there are many ways to accomplish this.  But this is a simple way that I would use.

Comment: A further change I would make, un-related to your question, is to check for newParent being null and only call addChild if newParent is not null.

Comment: So in essence, rather than add the Body to its parent in the constructor, just move that bit to the code that calls the constructor in the first place?  Only thing I'm concerned about is, it then becomes possible for a Body to become orphaned.

Comment: Given my answer there are two ways to orphan the child; forget to code the line right after the constructor, or call the setParent with null.  Maybe you can add isOrphaned() and return parent == null;  Then you can check for this where you need to.  There is a more complex way to accomplish this that I also like - use the builder pattern and have the build() method throw an error if the parent is not set.  Let me know if you are interested in that - I can add an answer for it.